# how to make flatelist a reusable component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, rxjs, react-hooks

i want to make my flatlist reusable but i am facing some difficulties while passing props.

code for the reusable component

```
const ListItemView = function (props) {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        //data={props.data}
        keyExtractor={props.keyp}
        renderItem={props.disptext}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

when i run console.log on the props i get this

{"disptext": undefined, "keyp": [Function anonymous]}

this is how i am passing props from the parent screen

```
const keyf = () => {
    console.log('keyf');
    //for the key extractor
    return (item => item.index);
  };
  const rendertext = () => {
    console.log('rendertext');
    //for rerender function of the flatlist
    ({ item }) => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>holaa</Text>
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  };
  return (
    <View style={style.container}>

      <ListItemView
        //data={con}
        keyp={keyf()}
        disptext={rendertext()}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

You are directly calling the function but you just need to give a reference of it...so that it is called only on some event.
It should be like this:

```
      <ListItemView
        //data={con}
        keyp={keyf}
        disptext={rendertext}
      />
```

or

```
 <ListItemView
        //data={con}
        keyp={()=>keyf()}
        disptext={()=>rendertext()}
      />
```